# how to convert the list of SyndicationItems to a string array

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have an rss feed reader which receives an rss feed and binds it to a `ListBox`.

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(feedXML);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader);
feedListBox.ItemsSource = feed.Links;
```

Instead I want to store the feed links in a string array so that I can use all those links somewhere else in my application. How should I do this?

Comment: SyndicationFeed.Links is a collection of SyndicationLink - and it has URI property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationlink.uri.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of the string repesentaion of the Uri you could just select them from feed.Links

```
 var links = feed.Links.Select(l => l.Uri.OriginalString);
```